# calling perl subroutine in shell script

Tags: perl, shell, perl-module

i made a Perl Module `MyModule.pm` it has some subroutines `getText` which I wanted to call in a shell script.
i tried following manner but it gives error;

```
SEC_DIR=`perl -MMyModule -e 'getText'`; # line 1
echo $SEC_DIR
exit 0
```

Returned Error;

```
Can't locate MyModule.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .).
```

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

PS: .pm file and .sh are at same location.
some other options I tried;

## line 1:

```
SEC_DIR=`perl -MMyModule -e '&getText'`;
SEC_DIR=`perl -MMyModule -e 'use MyModule; getText'`;
SEC_DIR=`perl -e 'use MyModule; getText'`;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to say what went wrong not knowing what's in `MyModule.pm`.

`@INC` looks ok (`.` is in the list, so there should be no problem with locating `MyModule.pm` in current directory).

Here's a minimal example that works the way you described. Hope it helps.

```
$ cat SomeModule.pm 
package SomeModule;

sub testsub
{
  return "it works\n";
}

1;
$ VAL=`perl -I. -MSomeModule -e 'print SomeModule::testsub'`
$ echo $VAL
it works
```

Another way to load the module would be:

```
$ perl -e 'require "./SomeModule.pm"; print SomeModule::testsub()'
it works
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but when i use your code with a '.' after 'I' then it shows same error, however when i remove '.' it echoes nothing. getText subroutine is returning a file path.

Comment: I've tested it on plain Ubuntu 10.10, with perl 5.10.1. With '-I.' the current directory is just searched for modules before any other directories.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI:  `perl -e 'do "./MyModule.pm"; getText'`