# Perl -M will not find a hardcoded path to a module

Tags: perl, csh

## Background

Inside a chsell script, I am invoking a subroutine from a perl module and saving its result to a variable in the [following manner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4377417/8981474):

```
set result =`perl -M/some/hard/coded/path/lib.pm=theFunction -e 'theFunction( $A_VARIABLE_ARGUMENT )'`
```

Despite the fact that I explicitly specify the module, my script throws this error:

> Module name required with -M option

## Question

How do I invoke a hardcoded module with perl's -M option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot, as the `-M` option is translated to a [use](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use) statement which takes only module names, not paths. However, you can add the path to be the first module search path using the `-I` option. Modules are searched relative to each [search path](https://perldoc.pl/variables/@INC) by translating them like `Foo::Bar` -> `Foo/Bar.pm`.

```
perl -I/home/hard/coded/path -Mlib=theFunction
```

As a note, you should definitely not call your module or package `lib`, because this is an important core module (in fact, it's what `-I` is using here).